# Yii 1.1 routes for some pages

Tags: php, yii, routes

I'm very new to routes.

The website is in Yii 1.1 as its very easy for me to write. Now I want that

- `http://someurl.com/admin`

points to

- `http://someurl.com/index.php?r=admin/index`

I have tried different things with no success.

Here is how I have tried to configure routes:

```
'urlManager' => array(
    'rules' => array(
        '<alias:admin>' => 'admin/index',
        '<alias:admin>' => 'site/<alias>',
        '<controller:\w+>' => '<controller>/view',
        'admin' => 'admin/index',
        'admin/index' => 'admin',
    ),
),
```

What is the solution?

Comment: maybe it's just a typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove the `?r=` part, you will have to set you url format to "path", In your config file:

```
array(
    ......
    'components'=>array(
        ......
            'urlManager'=>array(
            'urlFormat'=>'path',
        ),
    ),
);
```

I've not tested it but you route config should be:

```
array(
    'admin' => 'admin/index',
)
```

And to get rid of the `index.php`, you will have to change you apache configuration (if you're using apache obviously)

```
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

You'll find more detailed explanations in the doc: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url

Comment: my main.php (config) looks now like: `

// uncomment the following to enable URLs in path-format
  'urlManager'=>array(
       'admin' => 'admin/index',
  ),`
the http.conf from apache looks like:
`

RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php`

Comment: i use xampp local so i may have placed the rewrite in the wrong config file. according the docs it should be in the specific file for the site. as i use xampp locally, i do not have this. on my server i have this.

Comment: I've never use xampp but you can place the apache config in an .htaccess file in web root

Comment: i have done this, now i get a 404 when i try to acess localhost/iris/admin. any suggestions?

Comment: http://localhost/iris/index.php/admin is working fine. so i guess it must be something with the rewirte engine

Comment: Try to set the `RewriteBase` param in your apache config. Something like `RewriteBase /iris/`